# Get file size without downloading it

Tags: dart, flutter

How to get file size from URL (in Flutter)? I am able to get it by using:

```
http.Response response = await http.get(url);
print(response.contentLength);
```

But that downloads the entire file. Is it possible to get the file size without entirely downloading it? Thanks

Comment: Nope. You will have to store the size as a separate entry into your database or whatever when you write the response.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Found the answer: HEAD Request.

```
http.Response r = await http.head(url);
r.headers["content-length"]
```

Note: `r.contentLength;` directly doesn't work.

Comment: actually using the `dart.io` [HttpResponse](https://api.dartlang.org/stable/2.1.0/dart-io/HttpResponse-class.html) 's property `headers.contentLength` returns correct value.

Comment: Note that a head request doesn't always give the 'content-length'. For eg., Amazon S3 servers used for github release assets didn't give me the content-length header for a head request but it did when I did a get request.

Answer (score 1):

I tried the above-accepted answer for **firebase storage** file download size before download the file. But I see that **http.head** doesn't contain **content-length**. So I tried **http.get** method and I saw the **content-length** is contained in the header.So
This should be the correct answer I think.

```
http.Response r = await http.get(url);
final file_size = r.headers["content-length"];
```

Comment: i think with get you're downloading the file.